# comparable implementation in Java

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am new to Java and trying to implement MyLinkedList which extends the GeneralList interface, I want to use the comparable interface for my Node to keep my list sorted,
When I try to create a head node it is giving me errors

Please find the error message below the following code

```
//List interface

public interface GeneralList<T> 
{
    public boolean addNode(T elem);
    public boolean deleteNode(T elem);
    public T containsNode(T elem);
    public void printSll();

} 

//ListImplementation

public class SLL2<T> implements GeneralList<T> 
{   
    private static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> 
    {
        public T data;
        public Node<T> next;

        public Node() 
        {
            data = null;
            next = null;
        }
    }   

    public SLL2()
    {
        head = null;        
    }

    /* 1. Error while creating a head referance*/
    private Node<T> head;  

    @Override
    public boolean addNode(T elem) 
    {
        Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>();
        tmp.data = elem;

        if(head == null)
        {
            head = temp;
                        return true;
        }
        else
        {
              for(Node<T> cur = head; cur.next != null ; cur= cur.next) 
          {
                    /* iterate and add the node */
                    if(temp.elem.comparTo(cur.elem)) 
                    {
                    }

                }
           }
}

1. I am not able to create the head node with the declaration private Node<T> head;

It is giving error "Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type SLL2<T>.Node<T>"

Please help me to resolve this error...
```

Comment: You should change the generic parameter for `Node` (ie, `Node<E extends Comparable<E>>`). Cannot explain why, except that `T` is "already declared".

Comment: Re-read your class definitions carefully, and you should see the problem: from what you wrote, your `Node` class requires its generic parameter to be `Comparable`, but it takes its generic parameter from your `GenericList` class which doesn't force the parameter to be `Comparable`.

Comment: @fge not quite, `T` can be used as a class parameter for this static class with no problem (except it's not clear that it's not the same `T` as the list class - this coming from the fact `Node` is static). Using another name for the parameter might help clear things up, but won't change anything with regards to the error.

Comment: @GorkK I implemented sucessfully and moved to trees.Please help me, How to store the treeNode in a Queue
public class BSTImpl<T extends Comparable<T>> implements GenericTree<T>
{
 /* Inner class that defines the TreeNode */
 private static class TreeNode<T>
 {
  public T data;
  public TreeNode<T>left;
  public TreeNode<T>right;
           }
}
The following declaration is giving error
Queue<TreeNode<T>> q = new Queue<TreeNode<T>>();
Cannot instantiate the type Queue<BSTImpl.TreeNode<T>>

PS:your explanation was removed, which was very useful, if possible can you write again

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class `SLL2<T>` should also have a constraint about comparability of `T`. Like that:

```
public class SLL2<T extends Comparable<T>> implements GeneralList<T> {
    // ...
```

Comment: I want to have the comparable implementation to my custom object, How to write one for that
Lets say 
class CustomNode
{
int i;
string s;
float f;
}
I want to have comparator for the class which does compareTo for two CustomNode objects

Comment: @San1016, you should just implement the [`Comparable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your `CustomNode` class. Check the documentation; it should be straightforward. By the way, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted. It solved your original problem from the question, after all.